# Impossible ubuntu ocelot compiling cpp opencv

Tags: opencv, compilation

This morning I made the update to ubuntu ocelot, just to regret it some moments later, when I tried to compile one of my programs in opencv.
I checked the libraries path, and the shortcut command I creat on the .bashrc file, everything stills there, but the command doesn't work anymore, and when I try to compile using

```
gcv split.cpp slip
```

or without shortcut, like `g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann -lm`

But it gets a large errors list with a lot of messages like:

```
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:2600:13: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ does not name any type.
```

Has anyone any idea?

Thanks Iván

Maybe should I come back To ubuntu 11? where I had no problems?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure both of your computers have the same exact version of Opencv? 
I think the repo has been updated to 2.3.1 lately.

Comment: I have not update opencv,only ubuntu, but it is the same computer, and until before of the update everything worked fine.

Comment: Did you follow the manual install tutorial for ubuntu available on opencv.­willowgarage.­com ? You may have a dependancy missing after the update. I know some of the packages have changed.

Comment: It was a dependency problem, I had to reinstall ubuntu and then I followed the next page tutorial: a comprehensive guide to install and configuring opencv 2.3 on ubuntu. In this way, after some time working on it, i could manage. I had to change as well the include lines. After that everything worked.Thanks